Toilet drainage fernco - does this look OK?
I recently had a toilet drain repaired and when I looked in my crawlspace I noticed there were possibly some drips below the fernco. Does this look normal to you? It looks like the PVC pipe being bigger than the copper pipe is making the fernco uneven and I'm not sure that there is a good seal there. Is there a better fernco for the job? This picture was taken after I loosened the bolts (I thought the pvc might have just needed straightened), but you can see the PVC jutting out above the copper.


I wouldn't loosen the clamps, ( as you call bolts).  This looks similar to a Fernco Hulk coupling.  What it exactly is I cannot say.  Tighten the clamps back and dry the copper pipe. Use the toilet for a few days and see if there is a leak.  If so call the plumber back.

The second to the bottom clamp might be too high/close to the ridge.  I would like to turn it a bit and lower it, so more rounded near the two pipe edges.

Isn't a shielded coupling required in this situation?  Can't tell what OP has.
